# Excel 365 finds Unreadable Content in VS2012 Macro Template; Excel 2010 Does Not

Tags: visual-studio, excel, visual-studio-2012, vsto, office365

I am making some Excel document level customizations in VS2012.  When the published file is first opened in a local install of Office 365 I get the following error:

"Excel found unreadable content in filename.xltm. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes."

The strange thing is that the repair record is blank.  After:

```
 <repairedRecords summary="Following is a list of repairs:">
```

There isn't anything.  When I open the file in Excel 2010, I don't get the error.

My current work around is to open the file first in 2010, save it, and then distribute it.  After being opened and saved in Office 2010, I am not getting the error.

Is there a setting or something I need to change in VS2012?  I haven't been able to find information on this, and I've never run into a blank repair list.  The file functions fully as expected after the "repair" if saved over the initial file.

The xltm file doesn't contain any macros itself, and I have tried this on 3 different office 365 installs.